# Opencv face detection on live video feed using Qt Gui performing slow

Tags: python, qt, opencv, face-detection

I have a project where I need to design a `gui` in `qt`. This design contains a widget where `live video feed` will be displayed from a usb webcam using `opencv`. This project will detect `faces` and will also recognize them which means a lot of processing will happen on each frames.

For this what I have done is that I have created a thread which initialize the camera and takes frames from it using opencv. It then puts all the frame in the queue and this queue is then read by a function `update_frame` which basically displays the frame on qt widget. This is working fine with no delay.

Inside the `update_frame` function, I added the `face detection` due to which it was performing very slow. So I created another thread `start_inferencing` which basically reads frame from `queue` and after detecting face, it put the frame again in another queue `q2` which is then read by `update_frame` and it displays but still its responding very slow. Below is the code:

```
q = queue.Queue()
q2 = queue.Queue()

def grab(cam, qu, width, height):
    global running
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cam)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

    while running:
        frame = {}
        capture.grab()
        ret_val, img = capture.retrieve(0)
        frame["img"] = img

        if qu.qsize() < 100:
            qu.put(frame)
        else:
            print(qu.qsize())

class Logic(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        set_initial_alert_temp()

        self.window_width = self.ImgWidget.frameSize().width()
        self.window_height = self.ImgWidget.frameSize().height()
        self.ImgWidget = OwnImageWidget(self.ImgWidget)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(1)

        self.outside_temp_text_box.setText(str(curr_temp_cel))

    def update_frame(self):
        if not q2.empty():
            frame1 = q2.get()
            img = frame1["img"]

            img_height, img_width, img_colors = img.shape
            scale_w = float(self.window_width) / float(img_width)
            scale_h = float(self.window_height) / float(img_height)
            scale = min([scale_w, scale_h])

            if scale == 0:
                scale = 1

            img = cv2.resize(img, None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            height, width, bpc = img.shape
            bpl = bpc * width
            image = QtGui.QImage(img.data, width, height, bpl, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.ImgWidget.setImage(image)

def start_inferencing():
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            frame = q.get()
            img = frame["img"]
            face_bbox = face.detect_face(img)
            if face_bbox is not None:
                (f_startX, f_startY, f_endX, f_endY) = face_bbox.astype("int")
                f_startX = f_startX + 10
                f_startY = f_startY + 10
                f_endX = f_endX - 10
                f_endY = f_endY - 10
                cv2.rectangle(img, (f_startX, f_startY), (f_endX, f_endY), (0, 255, 0), 2)

                frame1 = {"img": img}

                if q2.qsize() < 100:
                    q2.put(frame1)
                else:
                    print(q2.qsize())

def main():

    capture_thread = threading.Thread(target=grab, args=(0, q, 640, 480))
    capture_thread.start()

    infer_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_inferencing)
    infer_thread.start()

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Logic(None)
    w.setWindowTitle('Test')
    w.show()
    app.exec_()


main()
```

Below is the summary of whats happening in the code:

```
camera -> frame -> queue.put                     # (reading frame from camera and putting it in queue)
queue.get -> frame -> detect face -> queue2.put  # (getting frame from queue, detecting face in it and putting the updated frames in queue2)
queue2.get -> frame -> display it on qt widget   # (getting frame from queue2 and display it on qt widget)
```

The main reason why the live video feed is slow is because the frame which is read in `grab` function is not able to process faster and thus the `queue` size keeps on increasing a lot and thus it overall becomes very slow. Is there any good approach I can use which can detect the face as well as show it without any delay. Please help. Thanks

Comment: May be use events (e.g. 'onFrame', 'onFaceDetected', etc.) ?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Can you please add more description

Comment: Your basic design appears to a producer/consumer series (or probably *should* be treated as such).  So why are you triggering `Logic::update_frame` from a ` milliseconds timer rather than simply blocking until the relevant queue has data?

Answer (score 1):

Queue accumulates the frames that the thread does not manage to process. So, no chanse to process them at all. That's why the queue useless here. Working clocks here defined by arriving frames, each frame generates event, which may work in it's own thread (let's say in processing thread) after frame processing is finished, processing thread generates another event and it processed in another thread, let's say in GUI thread and it shows the result to user.

If you mandatory need some buffer, check ring buffer it have finite lenght.

Comment: Thanks, I am not good in ring buffer or any buffer so for now will stick to queue but will definetly try in future

Answer (score 1):

You have a producer/consumer sequence...

1. grab frame and push on queue1
2. dequeue frame from queue1, process and enqueue results on queue2
3. dequeue results from queue2 and display

From what you've stated stage 2. is the bottleneck.  That being the case you could try assigning more resources (i.e. threads) to that stage so 2. has multiple threads reading from queue1, processing and pushing results onto queue2.  You just need to ensure that the processed data popped from queue2 is sequenced correctly -- presumably by assigning each initial frame with a sequence number or id.

Comment: Can you give me an example of queue or dequeue with id as you mentioned in your answer. Also I think what you mentioned in your comment is worth trying because there is no use of running update frame every milliseconds. I will try and update but do you think this pipeline is and can give good results